# Here when we compare if(vc[i]==vc1[i]) which is array of vector. actually what is the value which is compared,

Tags: c++, vector

```
int ismirror(vector<ll>vc[],vector<ll>vc1[],ll n){
  for(ll i=0;i<n;i++){
      reverse(vc[i].begin(),vc[i].end());
  }
  for(ll i=0;i<n;i++){
      if(vc[i]==vc1[i]){
         // cout<<vc[i]<<endl;      
          continue;
      }
}}
```

but when we try to print ***vc[i]*** then there is compile errorThanks

Comment: `vector<ll>vc[]` is an array of vector's of `ll`. Are you sure this is what you meant to pass?

Comment: Ask yourself: What is the type of `vc[0]`.  Is that a printable type?

Comment: no that's not but what is compared here

Comment: What is "ll"?  Is it itself a container?  Is it a numeric type?  And are you sure it's what you meant to use?

Comment: ll is a numeric type long long int which i have define but I have not posted whole code here

Comment: If ll is a numeric type, then calling .begin() and .end() on it doesn't make much sense.   The line reverse(vc[i].begin(),vc[i].end()); is trying to reverse the order of a single number, and is causing a compiler error in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `vc[i]` and `vc1[i]` are `std::vector` instances.

`vc[i] == vc1[i]` is calling `operator==` on `std::vector`. This compares `true` if the vectors have the same number of elements and the elements are all equal (note that the *capacity* of the vectors could be different).

`std::ostream` doesn't have an appropriate `<<` overload for `std::vector` so compilation of your `cout` fails.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: I missed the bit that explains how we know that `vector` in the code is the same as `std::vector`...

Comment: @TobySpeight: That's the least of our worries. `ll` is also not defined anywhere, and assignment to 0, `<`, and `++` could do completely unexpected things. See Boost Spirit for how you can do some really fancy things with expression templates and operator overloading! In the end I thought "Occam's Razor" and went for what I think is the most likely scenario.